# How to redirect QMessageBox text to a Textfile

Tags: c++, qt

In my project lots of time i am using QMessageBox. which is for warning / information . For e.g. If i am having some validation then at that time i am using some QMessageBox::information(…) , or if i want to restrict the user not to move out of a particular page then i am using QMessageBox::critical(…) . 
I know “How to redirect qDebug output to a file”.I want to do the same thing for the QMessagebox too. so that i will maintain a text file in my project folder . whenever the application run if the user encounters some message through QMessagebox , then that shall be redirected to that text file .So that after closing the application the user have a small list of messagedetails ,whatever he has encountered during running the application .

Please help me in writting this code ..

Thankxx in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your own static information, warning and critical functions that will show original QMessageBox and also write something to log.

```
static StandardButton information(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &text, StandardButtons buttons = Ok, StandardButton defaultButton = NoButton);

StandardButton information(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &text, StandardButtons buttons, StandardButton defaultButton) 
{
   qDebug() << "writing to log";
   return QMessageBox::information (parent, title, text, buttons, defaultButton)
}
```

Comment: Is there something like qInstallMsgHandler(..) ? 
since lots of times i have used this QMessagebox() in my project ,i have to do lots of changes in my project .
Can you please give some alternative solution ..
Thankx a lot for your reply ...

Comment: Hank is right, and he's got the answer. 
You can easy change all your QMessageBox'es or so on by using build in QtCreator `refactoring` -- right click on word (variable, type, ...) and choose `refactoring`, then choose what you want.

As for me, it is very useful feature `ctrl+shift+R` -- to rename symbol under cursor. Try it.